# IntelliJ runs unit tests with Maven instead of JUnit

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit-runner

I have some Unit tests, that when I try to run, it automatically creates `Maven` run/debug configuration, instead of `JUnit` (the integrated IDEA tab).

For some tests it does use JUnit `run\debug configuration` and manually - I can create both `Maven` and `JUnit`.

How do I make JUnit to be the default test runner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that I had `maven runner` plugin installed, causing all my tests to run with `Maven`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven option "-Dskip=true" to suppress the maven test execution, and you can add your own test configuration to the build process. This screenshot was taken form IntelliJ 15.0.2.

**Update: maven option**

[image: edit run configuration]
[image: output in "Run" view]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for. I want `ctrl+shift+F10` to use JUnit rather than mavenv's test runner.

Comment: in my example, I used the wrong maven option. Must be `-DskipTests`